# getting http post response body using curl

Tags: php, curl

So I have the following code snippet

```
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $jURL);
//Enable curl response
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//Enable POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//Use the $pData array as the POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jData);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo 'The body of the response is ' . $result;

curl_close($ch);
```

I would like to get the response body printed out, however my code above prints the number 1. Is there a way to get the response here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the first argument:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```